# Почему у нас так много непринятых ответов?

Tags: обсуждение

**Надо ли принимать ответы?**

По правилам форума, участники не обязаны этого делать. Можно проголосовать за ответ (он полезен), а можно его принять (он решил проблему автора вопроса).

**Я тоже принимаю не все ответы**, но обычно благодарю отвечающих и голосую за них.  Для меня любой ответ полезен, даже если он не совпадает с моим мнением, так как он  помог мне определиться. Но в этом случае я не могу его принять.

**А как поступают другие участники?** В общем-то все по-разному, но вот  некоторые из них меня **удивляют.** Допустим, человек задал 250 вопросов, сам при этом не отвечал. Принял где-то около 25 вопросов, то есть один вопрос из каждой десятки, девять ответов его не устроили.

**Просматриваю ответы,** в том числе и свои. По-моему, много хороших, развернутых ответов, люди искренне  старались помочь этому участнику решить его проблему,  не жалели сил и времени, но почему-то не помогли.

**А мой вопрос такой:  разве это нормальная ситуация?**

Если хорошие ответы, за которые проголосовали другие участники,  автор **систематически не принимает**, то, может, надо ему почаще **напоминать об этом**. Вообще-то этим должна заниматься система, но с системой трудно «договориться». Тогда **модераторы или их помощники** могли бы взять на себя этот вопрос. (Кстати, это касается и совсем новых участников, которые плохо знают правила и, возможно, поэтому не принимают ответы.)